# Add Workbook based on Template

Tags: excel, add-in, excel-2003, vba

I am writing a small VBA add-in for Excel 2003, the idea is that the add-in looks in a directory for any '.xlt' files and for each one it finds it adds a button to a 'Templates' menu which provides a quick way to get a blank template.  Most of the add-in works quite well but I am having trouble with one small bit and I am struggling to understand why it's not working.

Here is a sample of the code which builds the menu.

```
Public Sub BuildMenu()

Dim Active_Menu_Bar As Office.CommandBar
Dim Tmplts_MenuItem As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim Tmplts_MenuControl As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim objSearch
Dim TemplatesPath As String

DeleteControls

Application.Interactive = False

Set Active_Menu_Bar = Application.CommandBars.Item(1)
Set Tmplts_MenuItem = Active_Menu_Bar.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, , , 10, True)

With Tmplts_MenuItem
    .Caption = "Templates"
    .BeginGroup = False
    .Tag = C_TAG
End With

TemplatesPath = FetchValue("TemplatesPath")

Set objSearch = Application.FileSearch
    objSearch.LookIn = TemplatesPath
    objSearch.SearchSubFolders = False
    objSearch.Filename = "*.xlt"
    objSearch.Execute

For Each strFile In objSearch.FoundFiles

    'Remove Path from strFile
    strFile = Replace(strFile, TemplatesPath, "")

    Select Case strFile
        Case "Journal.xlt"
            Set Tmplts_MenuControl = Tmplts_MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
            With Tmplts_MenuControl
                .Caption = "New Journal"
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!NewJournal"
                .Tag = C_TAG
            End With

        Case "Budget Journal.xlt"
            Set Tmplts_MenuControl = Tmplts_MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
            With Tmplts_MenuControl
                .Caption = "New Budget Journal"
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!NewBudgetJournal"
                .Tag = C_TAG
            End With

        Case Else
            Set Tmplts_MenuControl = Tmplts_MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
            With Tmplts_MenuControl
                .Caption = "New " & strFile
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!NewGenericTemplate(""" & TemplatesPath & strFile & """)"
                .Tag = C_TAG
            End With

    End Select
Next

Set objSearch = Nothing

Set Tmplts_MenuControl = Tmplts_MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
With Tmplts_MenuControl
    .Caption = "User Preferences"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!UserPrefs"
    .BeginGroup = True
    .Tag = C_TAG
End With

Application.Interactive = True

End Sub
```

As you can see, there is a select case statement which says for particular 'known' templates assign a macro to the button in ordeer to handle the requirements of that template (for example the macro for the Journal template also populates a couple of fields on the template which will always have a particular value, such as the username being populated by `application.username`), this bit works as expected.

The problem is with the Case Else.  I want to be able to pick up any other templates which happen to be in the directory and pass the full path to a 'generic' macro which will just create a new workbook based on the template without any fancy extras so in the `OnAction` part of the `MenuControl` I'm passing the full path to the template over.

However, when I click on the menu control, nothing happens, no error message, nothing.

Here's the code for the `NewGenericTemplate` macro.

```
Sub NewGenericTemplate(MyTemplate As String)

Workbooks.Add Template:=MyTemplate
MsgBox MyTemplate

End Sub
```

Simple stuff (meaning I've probably forgotten something really obvious), I added the `msgbox` when I realized the menu button wasn't working and I wanted to check that the value was actually being passed over so now instead of nothing I get the msgbox (twice for some reason) and it shows the correct path to the template but the workbook doesn't get added.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.  I also tried setting a breakpoint in the `NewGenericTemplate` macro but the code doesn't break

Comment: The `NewGenericTemplate()` subroutine works for me in Excel 2010 if not called from a menu bar/add-in. I am however getting the exact behavior (duplicate msgbox, new file is **not** added) when I run it from an Add-in menu bar...

Comment: I also try changing it to `Workbooks.Add` (to add a blank workbook) and that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've had to put this question to the side for a few weeks but today I came back to it, I decided to go back to basics and just look for a method to pass a variable from a menu button to a macro which lead me to [this thread](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Pass_arguments_to_macros_from_buttons_and_menus_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/424.html).

What I have done now is change the `.OnAction` property from

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!NewGenericTemplate(""" & TemplatesPath & strFile & """)"
```

to

```
.OnAction = "'NewGenericTemplate """ & strFile & """'"
```

So basically removing the reference to the file which contains the macro.  I'm also only passing over the filename rather than the full path so below is the code I'm now using for the `NewGenericTemplate` routine.

```
Public Sub NewGenericTemplate(MyTemplate As String)

Dim TemplatesPath As String
Dim FullPathToTemplate As String

'Retrieve path to Templates Directory
TemplatesPath = FetchValue("TemplatesPath")

FullPathToTemplate = TemplatesPath & MyTemplate

If Dir(FullPathToTemplate) <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Add FullPathToTemplate
    Else
    MsgBox "Template File not Found, it may have been moved or deleted.", vbExclamation, "File Not Found"
End If

End sub
```

Hopefully that should be it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I was able to modify the suggestions from [this thread](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28365).

With the new control, add the `.Parameter` like so:

```
With Tmplts_MenuControl
   .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!NewGenericTemplate"
  .Parameter = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!NewGenericTemplate"
  .Caption = "New Generic Template"
  .FaceId = 99
  .Style = msoButtonCaption
  .BeginGroup = True
End With
```

Then, I modify the `NewGenericTemplate` subroutine to receive this `.Parameter`. Kind of. Since we can't reference the controls by index, since they appear to be dynamic, I simply loop over the existing controls/sub-controls, and assign `myTemplate` based on the control's `.OnAction` value.

```
Sub NewGenericTemplate()
Dim varControls As Variant 'top level controls
Dim ctrl As Variant 'secondary controls within top-level
Dim myTemplate As String

'Since I can't refernce the controls by Index (they are dynamic), we loop over them:
For Each varControls In Application.CommandBars("Command Bar Name").Controls '<--- EDIT AS NECESSARY
    For Each ctrl In varControls.Controls
        If ctrl.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!NewGenericTemplate" Then
            myTemplate = ctrl.Parameter
            GoTo EarlyExit:
        End If
    Next
Next

Exit Sub 'if no parameter has been assigned.

EarlyExit:
If Not myTemplate = vbNullString Then
    Workbooks.Add Template:=myTemplate
End If

End Sub
```

This is working successfully for me, where previous attempts had failed with the same issues you were experiencing.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking the time to look at this. From reading your answer I get the impression that you only expect there to be one button which calls the 'NewGenericTemplate' routine but I'm looking at there being multiple cases, your answer gives me something to get started with so going to go back and see what I can work out from it, if I get an answer I'll post it.

Comment: I think this approach might work for you. Each button will have a different `OnAction` and a different `ThisWorkbook.FullName` assigned to it, so the `If ctrl.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!NewGenericTemplate" Then...` should capture the information. You may need to make that `If ctrl.OnAction...` line a little bit more dynamic (`NewGenericTemplate` may need to be a variable string) but it seems like this may get you going.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks David, I may be looking at this the wrong way but I'm thinking that each button would have the same `ThisWorkbook.Fullname` assigned to it, because the templates add-in is building the menu then template.xla would be the value assigned to each one.  However I've actually managed to get it working a different way and will post the answer.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, with *this* code each one would refer to "template.xla" but with some modification you could probably work around that. It is a little tricky to add buttons at the `Application`-level that are `Workbook` specific, because you may have multiple workbooks open at a time, etc.  Good luck!